# How can one prove mathematically using a thought experiment that a simple pendulum will vibrate forever in an ideal condition (no friction)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, kinematics, vibrations

Let's say I have a simple vibrating pendulum, if there is no friction in the space, will it vibrate forever or will it stop? How can one prove this mathematically? I tried but failed, can somebody point me in the right direction?

$$L = \begin{bmatrix}|L|\cos(\theta)\\|L|\sin(\theta) \end{bmatrix}$$
$l$ is the length of the pendulum.

Then after some time force is applied to it which is caused by the gravity and the tension of the string (simplified):

$$F = \begin{bmatrix}
|T| \cos(\phi) - mg\\ |T|\sin(\phi)
\end{bmatrix}$$

After applying the force I get the vector (simplified):
$$X = \begin{bmatrix}
gt^2(\cos(\phi) - 1)\\gt^2\sin(\phi) 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now we add $L$ and $X$.
$$A_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
|L| \cos(\theta) + gt^2(\cos(\phi) - 1)\\ |L| \sin(\theta) + gt^2\sin(\phi) 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now we have found for $A_1$ we would apply the force and add the vector again and again and again to see if a pattern emerges. These are the equations I came up with.

**Note**: This is not the duplicate. See the edits.

Comment: how about $\dot E=0$?

Comment: 1) Draw you freebody diagram. 2) Write the resulting equations. 3) Look for terms that will decrease amplitude with time. 4) Edit your question with those things so we have something to work with.

Comment: @tpg2114 see the edits.

Comment: @Anonymous I already did. I suppose what you think the difference between this and the duplicate is that you are asking for the mathematical proof of it? And for what it's worth, I actually voted to close as homework-like and violating our policy on [check my work](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) questions, not as a duplicate (I was unaware of the dupe). So, while the edits might make it not a duplicate, I would still vote to close it for the check-my-work reason and so I won't nominate to reopen at this time.

Comment: And also our [so-called "homework" policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) but I ran out of room in the previous comment.

Comment: But, since you made edits to improve the question, I assume you will keep trying to improve it. So here's some more feedback that might help it become on topic... Explain your equations. What did you choose the terms you have in there? What do you think they mean? If you look at your final equation, you have a term with a periodic function multiplied by $gt^2$. Does this make sense? What happens as $t\rightarrow \infty$? What do you mean apply the force again and again to look for a pattern? What does your intuition about the physics tell you and do your equations agree?